# Matrix block indexing

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, julia

I am using Julia version 1.1.
I am working a lot with matrices that can be constructed from smaller matrices, e.g., the Pauli matrices. It is not clear to me how to efficiently construct big matrices by using a set of smaller matrices in Julia, i.e., directly write the smaller matrix into a certain index position.

Julias `kron` is not satisfactory since I would need to generate several "big matrices" to get my final result. E.g. I would like to create something like this (this is only a very small example)

```
sy = [[0 -im]; [im 0]]
M = [[0 sy adjoint(sy)]; 
     [adjoint(sy) 0 sy];
     [sy adjoint(sy) 0]]
```

It would be possible to do so by doing two kronecker products adding the two results. However this would be a huge waste, especially if the matrices got bigger.

I also already tried to work with the package `BlockArrays.jl` but realised that it does not fullfill my need.

In the end I want to be able to address "matrix blocks" of my big matrix so that I can directly assign the construction matrices to the right position, for the above example this would look like the following (I did not use a loop here to make my point clearer):

```
M[1, 2] = sy
M[1, 3] = adjoint(sy)
M[2, 1] = adjoint(sy)
M[2, 3] = sy
M[3, 1] = sy
M[3, 2] = adjoint(sy)
```

I realise that this means reducing my original big array indices to something like array "block indices".

I thought about doing this with views, where I create a matrix of `SubArrays` that I can then address with the matrix block index notation e.g.

```
S0 = view(M, 1:2, 1:2)
S1 = view(M, 1:2, 2:4)
S2 = view(M, 1:2, 4:6)
...

Viewmatrix = [[S0 S1 S2]; [S3 S4 S5]; [S6 S7 S8]]
Viewmatrix[1, 2] .= sy
Viewmatrix[1, 3] .= adjoint(sy)
...
```

Now it is unclear to me how one would actually go about this and write such a view matrix in general or if this is even a feasable way to address the problem. If there is a better way to approach this problem I would like to know it.

Comment: Can you specify what about BlockArrays does not fulfill your needs? E.g., they have the [block indexing](https://juliaarrays.github.io/BlockArrays.jl/stable/man/blockarrays/#Setting-and-getting-blocks-and-values-1) you're talking about.

Comment: The block arrays in `BlockArray.jl` always only divide the matrix into 2x2 blocks of arbitrary size. I need an arbitrary amount of blocks depending on the size of my submatrix and the size of the "big" matrix.

Comment: No, they don't -- that's just the only example they use. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BlockArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/BlockArrays.jl) does not only support 2×2 blocked arrays, although they used to use only them in their documentation.  You can easily create create the 3×3-blocked 6×6 array you want as follows:

```
M = BlockArray(fill(0im, 6, 6), [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2])
M[Block(1, 2)] = sy
M[Block(1, 3)] = adjoint(sy)
M[Block(2, 1)] = adjoint(sy)
M[Block(2, 3)] = sy
M[Block(3, 1)] = sy
M[Block(3, 2)] = adjoint(sy)

julia> M
3×3-blocked 6×6 BlockArray{Complex{Int64},2}:
 0+0im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0-1im
 0+0im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im
 ──────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────
 0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0-1im
 0+1im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im
 ──────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────
 0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0+0im
 0+1im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0+0im
```

But be careful: the blocks are stored by reference.  So if you modify `sy` afterwards, all blocks containing it will be changed as well, and vice versa.  If you want to avoid that, use broadcast assignment (`.=` instead of `=`).

If your problem is actually as simple as the example, and more on the dense side, it might be simpler to use the [`mortar`](https://juliaarrays.github.io/BlockArrays.jl/stable/lib/public/#BlockArrays.mortar) function to "stick together" the available blocks:

```
julia> mortar(reshape([z, sy, sy', sy', z, sy, sy, sy', z], (3, 3)))
3×3-blocked 6×6 BlockArray{Complex{Int64},2,Array{AbstractArray{Complex{Int64},2},2},BlockArrays.BlockSizes{2,Array{Int64,1}}}:
 0+0im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0-1im
 0+0im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im
 ──────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────
 0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0-1im
 0+1im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im
 ──────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────
 0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0-1im  │  0+0im  0+0im
 0+1im  0+0im  │  0+1im  0+0im  │  0+0im  0+0im
```

Although that uses an abstract type internally, instead of promoting the assigned arrays.

Comment: Very instructive answer, it's true that this usage was, to me, unclear from the documentation.

Comment: I have improved the documentation a bit now, based on your feedback.